# Drupal 7.12 Captcha module 7.x-1.0-beta2

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, captcha

As mentioned in the title I'm running Drupal 7.12. I'm having a little trouble with the Captcha module however. I can install and enable it without any problems. However when I go to "admin/config/people/captcha" the setting for the captcha module don't show up. Instead it shows the menu for "admin/config/people". If I go to my modules page to look at my installed modules it shows that captcha is installed. However if I click on the configure link associated with the captcha module it takes me to "admin/config/people". I've cleared my drupal and browser cache. Still nothing. I'm at my wits end what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other spam fighting modules installed? Mollom?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the module then uninstalling/re-enabling (Do not just disable it UNINSTALL it) the module.  If that doesn't work it must be an issue with some other module or code.  Make sure you run update.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding. I tried all that. I finally figured it out though. It was a database issue. I deleted all my modules. Then I had to run this: drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild. Then I reinstalled all my modules. After I did that everything worked fine!